# If $A=B$ doe $AC=BC$ where $A,B,C$ are matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B,C\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ (in fact there are even invertible, but maybe it's not so important). In an exercise they used the fact that since $Ax=Bx$, then $ACx=BCx$, and I'm not so sure about that. Indeed, if $f,g,h$ are functions, I agree that $$f=g\implies h\circ f=h\circ g,$$
but I don't think that $f\circ h=g\circ h$ hold. What do you think ?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't hold on the other side?  Examples?

Comment: Of course it hold ! What is not true would be $AC=BC$ implies $A=B$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perspective that might help.  If $Ax = Bx$ for all vectors $x$, then certainly $Ay = By$ for all vectors $y$.  If we set $y = Cx$, then we find that
$$
A(Cx) = B(Cx) \implies ACx = BCx.
$$
With the same kind of logic, you can prove that $f=g \implies f \circ h = g \circ h$.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider some fixed $x$, then $Ax=Bx$ does not imply $ACx=BCx$. However,

> For all $x$, $Ax=Bx$

implies

> For all $x$, $ACx=BCx$.